# Jbrowse-libpng not found

Tags: libpng, jbrowse

For jbrowse I use fink to install libpng, but I still can't get it working.  It spits out this error message:

> configure: error: libpng not found. Please install libpng and try
>   again. Or if it is already installed (e.g. in /usr/X11), pass the
>   include and link paths to configure like so: ./configure
>   CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/X11/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11/lib
>   + cd ../..
>   + set -x
>   + bin/wig-to-json.pl --key 'Image - volvox_microarray.wig' --wig docs/tutorial/data_files/volvox_microarray.wig --category
>   'Pre-generated images' --out sample_data/json/volvox

I don't really know what this error message means and when I type in the terminal

> ./configure CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/X11/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11/lib

It gives me an error that ./configure: No such file or directory.

I am a Novice at command line. Someone please help!

Comment: /usr/X11 would be a strange place to install libpng.  It's more likely in /usr/lib somewhere; type 'find /usr/lib -name "libpng*' to try to locate it.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  If it isn't in /usr/lib does that just mean that I actually didnt install libpng?

Comment: It either means you didn't install libpng or that fink put it somewhere else.  If you don't find it in /usr/lib you could try 'find / -name "libpng*"'; that will take a fairly long time and probably complain about a lot of directories (folders) that you don't have permission to read.  Sorry I don't know details about what "fink" does.

Comment: No worries, I used brew to install libpng, and when I do, I get an error message that says:

`brew install libpng

 > Warning: libpng-1.6.17 already installed, it's just not linked

> brew link libpng

 > Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.17... 

> Error: Could not symlink share/man/man5/png.5

>/usr/local/share/man/man5 is not writable.` Apologies for the terrible formatting

Comment: Thanks for the help I resolved this issue by doing `sudo chown -R user:admin /usr/local/share/man/man5` which made everything work!